# Stop thread from inside and notify from outside

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

Here's the basic concept of what I want to do

LEt's say I have thread one that looks like this.

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable{

    run(){

        while(true){
       //doWork and have thread 2 start working over a TCP connection, in my particular case
       wait();
   }

}
```

And thread 2

```
 public class Thread2 implements Runnable{

    run(){

       while(true){
       //doWork and now I need to wake up thread 1
       t1.notify(); //???
    }

}
```

This obviously doesn't work... My question is how to make this work basically. Both threads are created in main, so I can give them any information necessary to each other.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several schools of thought:

The first one is to have 2 threads, as in your example. They can share several types of objects through which *thread2* can notify *thread1*.

Using [`java.util.concurrent.Condition`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_concurrency/concurrency_condition.htm):

```
// thread1
public void run() {
    // to wait
    lock.lock();
    try {
        condition.await();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

//thread2
public void run() {
    // to notify
    lock.lock();
    try {
        condition.signal();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

You can also use [`CyclicBarrier`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cyclic-barrier), and maybe other types.

The second school of thought is to have a single work thread, which executes the other using [`ExecutorService`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial):

```
// thread2
public void run() {
    executorService.execute(new RunnableThread1());
}
```

This concept looks at the work done by *thread1* as a detached task which can be executed multiple times. So this may not be compatible with your program.

And the last option is to use [`Thread.interrupt`](https://www.javatpoint.com/interrupting-a-thread):

```
//thread1
public void run() {
    while (true) {
         try {
             Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
         } catch(InterruptedException e) {
             // signaled.
         }
    }
}

//thread 2
public void run() {
    thread1.interrupt();
}
```

This may be a bit problematic since the interrupt call is better used to stop threads and not to signal them.

Comment: very well explained. Thank you